# Using the struct itself in the definition of struct in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, flexible-array-member

I want to implement a simple tree struct in C++, like:

```
struct node{
    ....
    node* parent;
    node[]* children;
    ....
};
```

but the compiler reported an error (both CLang++ and G++)

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
node[]* child;
    ^

error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token
node(node[]* c): : child = c; {}
           ^
```

something like this

BTW, I'm using the -std=c++11 flag for some C++ 11 feature

any help is appriciated

Comment: It looks fine. Why don't you try  `vector<node *> children`?

Comment: *"the compiler reported an error"* - go on, give us a clue ....

Comment: You may want node* children[of_some_constant_size];

Comment: at least should paste the error...

Comment: @tristan the errors are here now

Comment: `node[]*` is a syntax error (regardless of what `node` is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of struct is compile time constant. If you give an array of `size to be determined later`, it is an error. Either give some size (For ex 2 in case of binary tree) or use `pointer to node *` to store an array or pointer (children) or use some builtin container (for ex std::vector, std::array)

Comment: Actually, unspecified-size arrays were standardized IIRC in C99, but I don't know if they made into C++11. The real problem there would be that such an array must be the last member of the structure (and that probably it isn't what OP wants anyway).

Comment: thank you! then I can just include the std::vector and use it to wrap things up right?

Comment: @MatteoItalia Unspecified-size arrays are C only (not permitted in C++)

Comment: @MatteoItalia the array is actually the last member in the structure, there are three constructors after it and nothing eles

Comment: @DieterLücking I thought that C++ inherits everything from C and added some new features...

Comment: For unspecified sized arrays in C++, order or construction and destruction would add many complications, so it is not available in C++11. (offcourse there are more reasons) Using STL looks like a clean solution.

Comment: @Z.Shang No, that is a misconception. A lot of C code is valid C++, but C++ isn't a super-set of C.

Comment: There are many more differences, you may try googling for differences between C and C++. [For example because C++ is more type strict, a code that compiles well and run (luckily) well in C may not even compile in C++]

Comment: Why do people say that C++ is more type strict? The only difference is implicit conversion from `void *`, which you would only do if you explicitly wanted to bypass the type system anyway

Comment: @juanchopanza I see, then my teacher of C++ (during my primary school) lied to me...

Comment: STL stands for [standard template library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). It defines set of reusable containers and algorithms to make your life easier. And because they are standard, you can use it anywhere. (They are guaranteed to be portable on other compliant targets with performance cap mentioned in specs)

Comment: @MohitJain thank you, so the vector / array things are in the STL right?

Comment: @MohitJain I mean the std::vector / std::array

Comment: Of course, whether the size of the array is specified or not is irrelevant for the moment, as his declaration doesn't even obey C or C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`node[]* children;` is not legal C++ syntax.  If the maximum
number of children is known at compile time, you can write:

```
node* children[maxChildren];
```

Otherwise:

```
std::vector<node*> children;
```

will do the trick.  If `maxChildren` is large or variable, you
might want to use this form anyway.  On the other hand, if
`maxChildren` is 2, you might want to just declare two pointers:

```
node* leftChild;
node* rightChild;
```